# flutter builder app shows error when i run `flutter build apk --release`

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, gradle

Hi i try to output my apk with Android API 26 platform but it shows error in terminal when i run `flutter build apk --release`, although i changed `targetSdkVersion` and `compileSdkVersion` to 26 in build.gradle file, also my `minSdkVersion` is 20.

here's error :

````
>flutter build apk --release

 Building with sound null safety 


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Android resource linking failed
     C:\Users\navid\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\2e94107f30f39be366a17347c2bf100b\core-1.1.0\res\values\values.xml:142:5-173:25: AAPT: error: resource an
droid:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.

     C:\Users\navid\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\2e94107f30f39be366a17347c2bf100b\core-1.1.0\res\values\values.xml:142:5-173:25: AAPT: error: resource an
droid:attr/ttcIndex not found.


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done                       6.0s
The build failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin. The tool is about to try using Jetifier to solve the incompatibility.
Building plugin flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle...
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'...                            |```

Evenit works when i use API 29 in project structure.
````

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the compileSdkVersion to:

`compileSdkVersion 28`

fontVariationSettings added in api level 28.

Comment: I did but it shows other error : `Note: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\google_maps_flutter-2.0.6\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\googlemaps\Convert.java uses or overrid
es a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\google_maps_flutter-2.0.6\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\googlemaps\TileProviderController.java
uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
`